# JPanel running on a JApplet

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I am designing a JApplet, and basically this applet will allow a user to draw a quadratic equation graph and it inserts the ranges of both x-axis and y-axis. But there is much more to do to reach that point.

I am still in the phase of designing the interface.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class Applet extends JApplet {
    JPanel p1;
    JPanel p2;
    JPanel p3;

    JScrollPane s1;

    public Applet() {

    p1 = new JPanel();
    p2 = new JPanel();
    p3 = new JPanel();

    s1 = new JScrollPane(p3,s1.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,s1.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    super.init();

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        p3.add(new JButton("Hello"));
        p3.add(new JLabel("blah"));
        p3.add(new JButton("Sup"));
    }

    p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()));
    p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(),(int) (this.getHeight()*0.6667)));

    p3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p3,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    s1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(),(int)(this.getHeight()*0.33333)));

    p1.add(p2);
    p1.add(s1);

    this.add(p1);
    }

}
```

Comment: My answer is already given by others :-), that too well nicely explained. Simply use nested Box, to put components where you want :-) +1 to all, though did that already yesterday :-)

Answer (score 4):

1. to have the x-axis and y-axis controls on top of each other, you should have two panels, one including the labels and text fields for the x-axis in one and those for the y-axis in the other.  You would then add those to a panel that is aligned vertically.  (`Box.createVerticalBox()`, for example)
2. You can make your `graph.java` an `ActionListener` of the 'Plot' and 'Refine' buttons.  In the `actionPerformed` method of graph.java, you can initiate a repaint, gathering the ranges from the 'ControlsB' instance.

EDIT: responding to your comments...

*'how to add another panel in order for me to place the x-axis above the y-axis'*

this can be as simple as (in ControlsB.java):

```
b = Box.createHorizontalBox();
b.add(new JLabel("Please enter range:  "));

Box b0 = Box.createVerticalBox();//create a vertical box to stack the controls

Box b1 = Box.createHorizontalBox(); // create a horizontal box for the x-axis

b1.add(new JLabel(" x-axis "));
b1.add(new JLabel("from"));
JTextField f1 = new JTextField("-5");
f1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
b1.add(f1);
b1.add(new JLabel(" to "));
JTextField f2 = new JTextField("5");
f2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
b1.add(f2);
b1.add(new JLabel(".   "));

Box b2 = Box.createHorizontalBox(); // create a second horizontal box for the y-axis
b2.add(new JLabel("y-axis "));
b2.add(new JLabel("from"));
JTextField f3 = new JTextField("5");
f3.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
b2.add(f3);
b2.add(new JLabel("to"));
JTextField f4 = new JTextField("-5");
f4.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,30));
b2.add(f4);

b0.add(b1); // add the x-axis to the vertical box
b0.add(b2); // add the y-axis to the vertical box
b.add(b0);  // add the vertical box to the parent

b.add(new JButton("Plot"));
b.add(new JButton("Refine"));
add(b); //is this necessary?
}
```

*' and how to gather the ranges from the ControlsB instance...'*

You should look into `ActionListener`s in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to understand how to make the button click events trigger action in a separate class.

Also, two critiques:

1. in your main class, `GraphApplet`, you are creating a `Box` before passing it into each of `ControlsA` and `ControlsB`'s constructor.  In the constructor, you then reassign the Box that you've passed in.  I don't think that you need to do that.  Either create the correctly aligned box in `GraphApplet`, pass that in and don't reassign, or don't pass anything in at all.
2. Your `ControlsA` and `ControlsB` classes both extend `JPanel`.  Although you go to the trouble of adding your `Box` containers to each of these at the end of their constructors, you don't ever add those Controls+ objects to any parent container. In your current implementation, i would suggest that extending `JPanel` is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to java, therefore if possible I would like to ask you for further details on the above answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Matthew: you should ask *specifically* about what isn't clear.

Comment: how to add another panel in order for me to place the x-axis above the y-axis and how to gather the ranges from the ControlsB instance...

Comment: Dear all, regarding the code you provided so that the x-axis is displayed above the y-axis is brilliant. Thanks a lot. Now regarding the issue I have with the action listener, in order for me to accept the values the user inputs, can anyone give me a tip on how to code it? thanks again

Comment: Matthew, i would suggest considering this question complete and creating a new question targeting the `ActionListener` issue.

Answer (score 4):

Recommendations:

- As for having one component on top of another, use a layout manager that would facilitate this such as a vertical BoxLayout.
- For having your display respond to a change in numeric data, I recommend that you design your program in a way to make this easy to implement, by using a [Model-View-Controller](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html) type application design. Pressing a "plot" or "refine" button would trigger the controller which would update the model's data. The view or GUI would listen for model changes and when they occur would re-plot the graph based on the model's latest data.