# ActionListener between two classes

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener, japplet

import javax.swing.*;

class Labels extends JFrame{
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

```
ImageIcon duke = new ImageIcon("duke.png");

JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel(duke);
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Duke is the friendly mascot of Java technology.");
JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel ("Duke", duke, JLabel.CENTER);

public Labels(){

    super("Swing Labels");
    setSize(1000 , 800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(pnl);
    setVisible(true);

    lbl1.setToolTipText("Duke - the Java Mascot");

    lbl3.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    lbl3.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);

    pnl.add(lbl1);
    pnl.add(lbl2);
    pnl.add(lbl3);

}
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Labels gui = new Labels();
    }
```

}

What if I want to use this as a JApplet? what has to be done? Is it hard to change?

The things that run on a JFrame are the same as the ones on a JApplet?

Comment: To clarify ControlsB must implement  an action listener in a seperate class and the actionlistener class should prompt user for values and pass or initiate Graph class with those values?

Comment: I need that xaxis1,xaxis2,yaxis3,yaxis4 in the ControlsB.java which are inputed but the user (as you can see in the diagram I uploaded) are linked to the variables f,g,yaxis3,yaxis4 found in the Graph.java by an ActionListener which has to be in another class.

Comment: Simply send an object of your `Graph` Class to the class which handles `Events`, and let that class call the `setValues()` method of your `Graph` Class, each time you modify a value, the last statement of this `setValues()` method will be `repaint()`, so with each value change, it will repaint the `JPanel` :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw I have revised my question. In the update do you think I am on the right track? Please not that the code does not compile yet. It is still under construction

Comment: @Matthew : First of all do one thing, what ever variables you think are  responsible for drawing that graph, make them `Instance Fields/Class Fields`, bring them out of your `paintComponent(...)` method, don't keep them as local, make them Instance Variables. No worries I got your previous code, just bring these variables out, I might can make that work, just update Graph class with `Instance Variables`. Once you have updated , you might can remove the previous code from the question, to reduce it's length

Comment: May you please, explain me how to draw this line. Like e.g. I enter four points, x1, y1, x2 and y2, will the code inside `paintComponent(...)` be able to calculate by itself, how to plot a line on the graph for these points, or I have to do something more than this ?

Answer (score 3):

As I recommended in [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11064580/522444), you should re-organize your program to conform to the [Model-View-Controller](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html) pattern, or one of its variants, as this will allow you to cleanly separate out the control code (that called by the ActionListener) from the GUI. For an example of an M-V-C program, please check out my suggestions and code in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066221/522444).

Comment: org.jdesktop.swing.animation.demos/SplineEditor has great example, previously +1, delayed because I cann't remember impression from OP's figuge, EDIT aaaacch welcome to >50k users

Comment: @Hovercraft I am new to java, and unfortunately the links you gave me are confusing me at the moment :s thanks anyways for your input.

Comment: @Matthew: the code you've posted does not compile making understanding and testing difficult.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the Graph.java is not complete and the RangeXYInput is still under construction, but the problem is I don't know how to proceed :S If required I will post all the codes complete in order for you to understand what the RangeXYInput class should do... Please Advise

Answer (score 3):

Well okay first check this out: [action listener in another class - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985507/action-listener-in-another-class-java)

now all you have to do is edit it to your needs, and in the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` you will then get the values in controlB.java class by accessing the data using a accessor/get method or make the Actionlistener class extend the ControlB so it will have access to all its public data, then once you have the values, pass them to the Graph.java either during initiation or using a mutator/set method?

Answer (score 3):

Some class, preferably an inner class of B if you're going  to allow input only from JPanel B, has to implement ActionListener. That ActionListener has to be added to the JTextField:

```
myInputTextField.addActionListener(theActionListenerIAmGoingToWrite).
```

That ActionListener has to define actionPerformed() something like this :

```
String text = inputTextField.getText();
Integer inputInteger = Integer.getInteger(text).toInt(); 
graph.doStuffWithIntegerInput(inputInteger);
```

The design questions to be answered are :

Is the ActionListener an anonymous inner class? If you're only going to use it with a specific instances of graph and B which know about each other, then go this way. If so, it has to get a reference to the Graph instance from its containing class, which implies B has such an instance to offer it.

Is the action of the ActionListener reusable elsewhere? Will the "enter numbers" widget appear elsewhere on other JPanels? If so make it a stand alone class. You still need a reference to graph so  either graph in as a constrcutor parameter and/or have a setGraph method because somehow it needs to know about the graph instance so it can send it a message.

done!

**edit 2**

OK so let's map what you have to an MVC framework. So your view consists of the Graph class and your class B and your textFields.

Now contained within your graph  class, you also have the data  you want to graph. That's the start, finish, x , y variables you've defined.  To be a good citizen of MVC-land, you  would have to pull these out and contain  them within a separate object b/c they constitute the **model** of your graph. A model is, very basically, the set of facts you wish to present, irrespective of how they are going to be presented, while  the **view** is all the code concerned with painting stuff to the screen.

So this model object would be a simple data object with getters and setters for all the variables you've defined and would be passed into the Graph object either at the constructor or through a setter on the Graph object.

By creating this  GraphData object, you've separated the view, the Graph from it's model the GraphData object.

With a  more complicated Graph, you'd actually specify in a GraphModel what "kind" of Graph object you want to create, what the axis names would be, what kind of line you want to draw,  stuff like that, but that's overkill for what you have.

OK so now you have your Graph and GraphData objects and some way to get them together.

Next let's look at your class B. Since it's a JPanel, a view, it's essentially an aggregator and presenter of its contained Views. Those would be the Graph and the JTextFields. So you add them as you have, specifying the layout.

So a hypothetical refactoring goes like this:

Create main program. In that main create: JTextFields, ActionListener, JPanel (B), Graph and GraphModel.

Associate GraphModel with Graph.

Associate Graph with JPanel.

Associate ActionListener with JJtextField

Associate JTextField with JPanel

As far as writing ActionListener goes just make it its own class, that's the easiest to write and understand. So thus:

```
public class MyTextFieldListener implements ActionListener
{
   private Graph graph;
   public   MyTextFieldListener(Graph graph)
   {   
      this.graph = graph;
   }// construtor

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) 
  {
      String text =  ((JTextField)ae.getSource()).getText();
      Integer inputInteger = Integer.getInteger().(text).toInt();
      graph.doStuffWithIntegerInput(inputInteger); 
  } // actionPerformed
}// class
```

Now a complication could be that you can't update the graph until you have info from all four textfields. There are different ways to change this code to accommodate that but this is the basic idea of where you need to go.

HTH

Comment: so if I understood feel your answer, I am supposed to insert that piece of code you provided me inside the ControlsB.java, and there is no need to create another class for the action listener?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK.  Let's talk about your  RangeXY object. What is its purpose? I ask because it seems to not need anything from the JTextFields , that is from the user input.

Where you're calling graph.doStuffWithIntegerInput(), actually, you're not using the integer input from the user, which is what comes from the text field. You're using (and this is just wrong) an int you passed into the constructor of RangeXY. Then you're (and here comes the "just wrong" part) giving that int to the Integer static method getInteger(). Actually, that wouldn't compile since getInteger takes a String and turns it into an Integer.

OK so let's just do this. Do one thing at a time. First, write a class that fits this description:

It implements ActionListener;
It has a member variable for Graph;
THe member variable for Graph is set either in a setter or passed in to the constructor.
It has an EMPTY actionPerformed method (for now)

Just do that and we'll take it from there.

Comment: I'm the guy who was answering your question above... I lost my password and access to that other email so I had to start over with a new account. .. there go all my credits or points or whatever!!! LOL

Comment: All those virtual beers down the drain .. ;-) Seriously though, I am not involved in the thread  :) but *which* "guy who was answering your question" are you - John or David?

Comment: @user1462475 if i remove the file RangeXY file and instead the class controlsB I make it: "class ControlsB extends JPanel implements ActionListener" will this work? Now if this is possible I need the program to be in such a way that when the user inputs the values of range x and y and he hits the resize button the values are transfered to the Graph.java file and the graph is repainted with the new variables. Thanks :)

Comment: Leigh I was  John now I'm.. someone else...Matthew .. yes it will work and yes I understand what you want but if you can just bear with me and make GraphListener its own class you'll learn more about inner classes anonymous classes etc... just write a class named GraphListener and have it implement ActionListener .. you don't  have a hard problem really you just happen lack the requisite knowledge, a thing we're going to fix right now...